# Display categories being supplied by a supplier

Tags: php, html

I have my 2 tables : `tbl_supplier` & `tbl_categories`

I want to display all the categories being supplied by a supplier in a dropdown `select` option in `php` html

Example:

```
 Supplier1 > Category1, Category2, Category3

 Supplier2 > Category2, Category4
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you be a bit more specific ?

Comment: I tried putting a fieldname "supplier_id" in tbl_categories but it only shows 1 category. I wanted to display all the categories being supplied by a single supplier

Comment: can you tell the structure of your tables?

Comment: you say you have 2 tables; HTML tables? database tables? If database; which api is used to connect with? Your question is unclear in those areas including the HTML you mention.

Comment: **Stack isn't a free coding service or research facility.** Please try something, then edit your post to contain what that was and may have experienced difficulties with; we'll be glad to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a third table with one row per Supplier/Category combination:

Supplier

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Ana  |
| 3  | Dan  |
```

Category

```
| id | name       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | category 1 |
| 2  | category 2 |
| 3  | category 3 |
```

Supplier_categories

```
| id | Supplier_id | categ_id |
|----|-------------|----------|
| 1  | 1           | 1        |
| 2  | 1           | 2        |
| 3  | 2           | 2        |
| 4  | 2           | 3        |
```

Then you can retrieve a list of each supplier categories by doing `INNER JOIN` to the three tables and putting conditions like this:

```
SELECT Supplier.id, Category.name
FROM Supplier
INNER JOIN Supplier_categories
on Supplier_categories.Supplier_id = Supplier.id
INNER JOIN Category
ON Category.id = Supplier_categories.categ_id 
WHERE Supplier.id = 1 //(for example)
```

Comment: can i use this in dynamic dropdowns? like i have this first dropdown for supplier showing the supplier list. when I select one, the second dropdown "categories" will display the categories being supplied by the selected supplier?

Comment: Yes. You can do that by selecting all the categories of all suppliers (each supplier connected to the categories it has .. like in the query above) and that will be by PHP for example using variables. Then you can output javascript variables containing the resulted categories and suppliers and make a javascript function to dynamically switch between the categories for each supplier selected from the first dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tbl_supplier contains a sid primary key, and then that key is present in tbl_categories to keep track of suppliers, and cat is the column to hold category name, the query would be like this: 
 `Select c.cat from tbl_supplier as  t, tbl_categories as c where t.sid=c.sid and t.sid='supplier-1'`
Example for Supplier 1:

```
<label>Supplier1:</label>
            <select name="supplier-1">
            <option>All</option>
                <?php 
                $query = mysqli_query($conn,"Select c.cat from tbl_supplier as t, tbl_categories as c where t.sid=c.sid and t.sid='supplier-1'");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    echo "<option>".$row['cat']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

However, if you would like to dynamically add multiple suppliers dropdowns then you would need to write a more complex query.
 Hope I helped!